# person's name vs persons' name

Tags: spelling

which one is correct, when talking about names of a group of person :

> ....persons' name
>
> ....person's name

I guess that the first one is correct, because, persons is plural and also I guess that name should be singular, because in this group of persons, every one has **one** name, other way we should say, I guess, **persons' names**

Comment: Person is a singular noun, so I'll leave you to figuring out where the apostrophe goes.

Comment: what If I wanted to talk about a group of person ?

Comment: "Persons" in the plural is hardly ever used in everyday English: the normal plural of "person" is "people". "Persons" only occurs in legal and official contexts.

Comment: "**The name of each individual in a group**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> people's names

The form "persons" doesn't exist in normal English.  It does exist in some English jargons, but that's an exceptional case and it carries a range of slightly different meanings.

Unless all of the people in the group are expected to share the *same* name, "names" should be plural.  Each person normally has one name, so several people would provide several names.

If you ask "what are those people's name?", leaving "name" singular, you should get only one name in return, such as "that's the Johnson family" or "that's the Thunderbolt bowling league", or even "they don't have a name; that's just a group of friends".

> each person's name
>   every person's name

This structure shows the relationship that you expected.  The adjectives "each" and "every" allow us to consider the members of a group individually.  This form shows that we expect one person to have one name, the next person to have another name, and so on.